# TypeError while bit shifting array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I get an error when triyng to right_shift an array with numpy:

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((10, 10)) * 64
a.astype("int16")
b = a >> 2
```

And I get

```
TypeError: ufunc 'right_shift' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

But according to the [docs](http:////https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.right_shift.html), it seems to me this should work.

Comment: Try ```a = a.astype("int16")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `astype` method can not operate in place because it casts elements to a different size in the general case. Floats are generally 64 bits, while `int16` is clearly 16 bits.

Consequently, the line `a.astype("int16")` is a no-op.

You can either write it as

```
a = a.astype("int16")
```

or merge the last two lines:

```
b = a.astype("int16") >> 2
```

In general, however, using `astype` is code smell. Numpy provides the facilities for allocating arrays of the correct type and value to start with:

```
a = np.full((10, 10), 64, dtype=np.int16)
b = a >> 2
```